# Perl decoding, for looping, & downloading

Tags: perl

I wrote this script but I'm not sure if it is correct.

What I want to do is process a JSON file by reading its content, decoding it, and looping through each item as `$item`. The contents from a certain URL with the ID defined as `$items[$i]['paper_item_id']` are saved with that ID into the defined destination.

But the code doesn't seem to function. I'm not sure on where I went wrong but any help or tips to improve the code and make it work would be good.

I'm not asking you to do the job, just need help seeing on where I went wrong and correct it for me.

The script should basically decode the JSON and then download the swf files from a certain directory URL to a directory on my PC using the IDs.

This is the code

```
use LWP::Simple;

$items = 'paper_items.json';
my $s = $items or die;
$dcode = decode_json($items);

for ($i = 0 ; $i < $count ($items) ; $i++) {

  use File::Copy;

  $destination = "paper/";
  copy(
    "http://media1.clubpenguin.com/play/v2/content/global/clothing/paper/"
        . $items[$i]['paper_item_id'] . ".swf",
    $destination . $items[$i]['paper_item_id'] . ".swf"
  );
```

Comment: you cannot use "http://..." url as a valid source in a File::Copy copy operation

Comment: (1) the string `paper_items.json` isn't JSON. (2) Even if it were, you do nothing with the decoded data structure `$dcode`. (3) The syntax `$count($items)` does not exist. If you want to iterate through the elements of an array, do `for my $elem (@array) { ... }`. To iterate indices: `for my $i (0 .. $#array)`. (4) `File::Copy::copy` cannot handle URLs as far as I know. You want `LWP::Simple::mirror`. (5) Hashes are indexed like `$hash{key}`. They aren't arrays. (6) Always `use strict; use warnings;` and fix those problems.

Comment: Also provide the content of your JSON file, or else it is difficult to see how the looping should be done correctly.

Comment: http://media1.clubpenguin.com/play/en/web_service/game_configs/paper_items.json this is the json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program can be broken down into three steps:

1. Fetch the JSON source.
2. Parse the JSON.
3. Iterate over decoded data structure. We expect an array of hashes. Mirror files denoted by the `paper_item_id` to the working directory.

We will use `LWP::Simple` functions here.

Our script has the following header:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;   # disallow bad constructs
use warnings; # warn about possible bugs

use LWP::Simple;
use JSON;
```

#### Fetching the JSON

```
my $json_source = get "http://media1.clubpenguin.com/play/en/web_service/game_configs/paper_items.json";
die "Can't access the JSON source" unless defined $json_source;
```

That was easy: we dispatch a `get` request on that URL. If the output is undefined, we throw a fatal exception.

#### Parsing the JSON

```
my $json = decode_json $json_source;
```

That was easy; we expect the `$json_source` to be an UTF-8 encoded binary string.

If we want to inspect what is inside that data structure, we can print it out like

```
use Data::Dumper; print Dumper $json;
```

or

```
use Data::Dump; dd $json;
```

If everything works as expected, this should give a screenfull of an array of hashes.

#### Iterating

The `$json` is an array reference, so we'll loop over all items:

```
my $local_path = "paper";
my $server_path = "http://media1.clubpenguin.com/play/v2/content/global/clothing/paper";

for my $item (@$json) {
  my $filename = "$item->{paper_item_id}.swf";
  my $response = mirror "$server_path/$filename" => "$local_path/$filename";
  warn "mirror failed for $filename with $response" unless $response == 200;
}
```

Perl has a concept of *references*, which is similar to pointers. Because data structures like hashes or arrays can only contain scalars, other arrays or hashes are only referenced. Given an array reference, we can access the array like `@$reference` or `@{ $reference }`.

To access an entry, the subscript operator `[...]` for arrays or `{...}` for hashes is seperated by the dereference operator `->`.

Thus, given `%hash` and `$hashref` to the same hash,

```
my %hash = (key => "a", otherkey => "b");
my $hashref = \%hash;
```

then `$hashref->{key} eq $hash{key}` holds.

Therefore, we loop over the items in `@$json`. All of these items are hash references, therefore we use `$item->{$key}`, not `$hash{key}` syntax.

Comment: Well, that iterating 404s for me, but otherwise it works fine.

Comment: Yes it download's some swf's and it keeps showing 404s here and there.

Comment: Well, some URLs simply don't exists, e.g. `http://media1.clubpenguin.com/play/v2/content/global/clothing/paper/1.swf`. Are you sure you have the right path and have interpreted the meaning of the API correctly? If you want to silence any errors, you can just uncomment the `wanr` line.

Comment: Oh yeah I see why, some of them don't require paper.There's other two directories too http://media1.clubpenguin.com/play/v2/content/global/clothing/sprites/ and http://media1.clubpenguin.com/play/v2/content/global/clothing/icons/                                                                                    However thank you so much for everything mate :)

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is to download the Shockwave Flash resources from Disney's Club Penguin game site.

I cannot imagine Disney would be too happy about this, and the site's [terms of use](http://www.clubpenguin.com/terms-of-use/en) say this under "Use of Content" (*"DIMG"* is *Disney Interactive Media Group*)

> Except as we specifically agree in writing, no Content from any DIMG Site may be used, reproduced, transmitted, distributed or otherwise exploited in any way other than as part of the DIMG Site ...

Comment: @user2524169: It isn't me you have to persuade. The terms of use prohibit what you are doing, regardless of whether you credit the source. If your cause is a good one then I can imagine Disney may well be sympathetic if you ask for them to *"specifically agree in writing"* that you can use their resources.

Answer (score 0):

Code is untested.

```
use File::Slurp qw(read_file);
use JSON qw(decode_json);
use LWP::Simple qw(mirror);

for my $item (@{ decode_json read_file 'paper_items.json' }) {
    my $id = $item->{paper_item_id};
    mirror "http://media1.clubpenguin.com/play/v2/content/global/clothing/paper/$id.swf", "paper/$id.swf";
}
```